# How to migrate COBOL source code to clearcase

Tags: clearcase, cobol, mainframe

I have all my COBOL source code located on a [z/OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z/OS) mainframe. What is a way to migrate all this code to ClearCase?

Answer (score 3):

[Rational Developer for System z](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/rational/products/developer/systemz/) (RDz) is the tool you should be using for this. It's basically Eclipse with a large number of IBM proprietary plug-ins which give you access to your mainframe data sets, including those under the control of SCLM (the default z/OS source code management system).

You can use RDz to connect to the mainframe and check out your code directly into an Eclipse project. That code can then be added to any other source code management system that has an Eclipse plug-in.

There's more to it of course, such as the ability to kick off mainframe builds from the Eclipse environment, something that will be important since, no matter how hard you look, you probably won't find many distributed platform compilers that can compile mainframe source.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need a one-time move, a file packing tool -- like PKZip/MVS or UnXMIT -- to bundle the source up.  You can then transmit it using IND$FILE, ISPF File Transfer or FTP to your clearcase server and check it in.

If you need ongoing updates of your mainframe resources on a server based source control system, you might be better off setting up some shared DASD using samba, NFS or the like between your mainframe and your server.

Unless you plan on doing your development on PCs, I don't think Rational Developer for Z is going to be a good fix.  It will do what you need, but the mainframe setup is kind of headache-y and the cost of the product is excessive if all you need is to move resources to/from your clearcase server.

IIRC, RDz costs about 6k per seat.  You might spend a few days writing some procs to ftp to/from your clearcase server and check-in/check-out and save some heafty expense.  Actually, IBM ought to already have those tools built already.  Clearcase supports remote machines doing checkin/checkout, maybe all you need is USS and a TCP/IP connection.